# read.csv() reads the data.frame OK readr::read_csv() for the same data.frame fails, why?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, dplyr, tidyverse

below, when I read in my data.frame using `readr::read_csv()`, my subsequent code produces `NA` for `yi`.

But when I read in my data.frame using Base R's `read.csv()`, my subsequent code correctly computes `yi`.

I wonder what's going on?

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpqq/w/main/n.csv")
d2 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpqq/w/main/n.csv")


d %>% group_by(study) %>%  # change `d` to `d2` and compare the results
  mutate(n = unlist(mean(c(nT,nC))),
         N = nT+nC,
         w = (nT+nC-2)*.8,
         icc = .15,
          yi = ifelse(assign_type=="group", yi*w, yi)
  ) %>% ungroup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default `read_csv()` converts empty strings to `NA`.

Try  `d <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpqq/w/main/n.csv", na = c("NA"))`

Both data sets should be the same now.

Comment: Well, in my own code I read the data locally using `readxl::read_xlsx("d.xlsx", na = "NA")` and again it doesn't work.